# I am getting an error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am getting an error when i am using datepicker .The code breaks at datepicker.js
Here I am attaching my code
datepicker.js

```
$(function () {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

the html page where my datepicker should be displayed:
ReportDetails.html

```
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <div ng-app="TimeSheet" data-ng-controller="headerCtrl" class="container">
            <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            </div>
            <p><a data-ng-click="showadd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</a></p>
            <div class="modal fade" id="userModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-hide="editMode">Add Project ID</h4>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-show="editMode">Edit Project ID</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="adduserform">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">UserID</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select data-ng-model="user.userid" class="form-control" id="title" required>
                                            <option value="" selected="selected">(Select User ID)</option>
                                            <option value="user1">user1</option>
                                            <option value="user2">user2</option>
                                            <option value="user3">user3</option>
                                            <option value="user4">user4</option>
                                        </select>

                                        <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="user.userid" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter your User ID" required title="Enter your UserID" />-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        Active <input name="Status" type="radio" data-ng-model="user.ResultStatus" value="Active" required title="Choose status">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        In-Active <input name="Status" type="radio" data-ng-model="user.ResultStatus" value="InActive" required title="Choose status">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input name="startDate" data-ng-model="user.date" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
                                        <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="user.projectid" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter your Project ID" required title="Enter your ProjectID" />-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </span>
                                        <span data-ng-show="editMode">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Headers List</h1>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>User ID</strong></td>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td>
                        <p>{{ user.userid }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>{{ user.ResultStatus }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <a data-ng-click="edit(user)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My main page - index.html where you can find all the file imports

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="../app.js"></script>
    <script src="../Controller/HeaderCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../lib/datepicker.js"></script>





</head>
<body ng-controller="headerCtrl">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
        <p>
            <br />
        </p>
        <b><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white">Administrator</a></b>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#AddHeader">Header Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ProjectIDCreation">Project ID Creation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ReportDetails">Report Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Display all submission for verify</a></li>
        </ul>
        <b><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white">User</a></b>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Timesheet Information</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <ul id="login_signup">
            <li><a href="#" id="login_link">Login <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="sign_link">SignUp <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

code snippet from index.css

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: if the call to `datepicker` happens in app.js, then it happens before `datepicker.js` was loaded. Try to change the order of loading the JS files.

Comment: I see that you've imported multiple `jquery.min.js`. It is redundant, and possibly, could be the source of error

Comment: What a mess!! Loading 3 versions of jQuery.js and several angular.js. Clean up your inventory

Comment: oh ok...let me clear them and test

Comment: Do you import jQuery UI to the relevant page ReportDetails.html where you are calling the datepicker?

Comment: If you can please put all the javascripts above the body closing tag. Just for blocking concept.